# Uploading Excel-File to WebDAV

Tags: javascript, webdav

i'm trying to upload an excel file that got created through exceljs. The file-creation works, but the upload to the WebDAV doesn't work.

I tried different examples of webdav-client, but can't get it together quite right. This one was my last try.
The following code throws 'Argument error, options.body'.
Running the code with readFileSync also throws the error.

```
exports.saveToWebDAV = (file) => {

    const conOptions = {
        url: '',
        authenticator: new webdav.DigestAuthenticator(),
        username: '',
        password: '',
    }

    const connection = new webdav.Connection(conOptions);

    fs.readFile(file, function (err, data) {
        if (err) throw err;
    
        const buffer = Buffer.from(data);
        connection.put('/' + file, buffer, (error) => {
            if (error) throw error;
        });
    });
    
}
```

The example for a simple textfile worked, which is this here:

```
const myNotes = 'The answer is 42!'

connection.put('/path/to/myNotes.txt', myNotes, (error) => {
    if (error) {
        throw new Error(`File upload did not work: ${error}`)
    }
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately your answer doesn't work.
But your answer actually brought me to the original code and test-code from the library and finally to the conclusion.

Wrapping the data into the options.body doesnt work, because the library already does that.

The Error actually comes from fs, which couldnt really read the files data. I got it working with the following workaround:

```
const connection = new webdav.Connection(conOptions);

let absolutePath = path.resolve(filename);

const data = fs.readFileSync(absolutePath);

connection.put('/' + filename, data, (error) => {
    if (error) throw error;
});
```

I'll change the function to use absolute Paths in the future, it's much easier to get the absolutePath in the code that invokes the function, since it gets created there.

Appreciate the help!